# @Validated annotation makes field of @ConfigurationProperties class to be null

Tags: java, spring, validation, initialization, configurationproperties

I have the following two classes and yaml-config:

**Class 1:**

```
 @ConfigurationProperties
 @Validated     ֎ 1 ֎
 public class SplitterProps {

    @Valid
    public final ConnectionParams connectionParams;
 //   @Valid
 //   @NotNull
    public final Subscriber subscriber;
    public final List<@NotNull @Valid Converter> converters;

    @ConstructorBinding
    public SplitterProps(ConnectionParams connectionParams,
                                Map<String, Subscriber> subscribersList,
                                List<Converter> converters) {
        this.connectionParams = connectionParams;
        this.subscriber = subscribersList.isEmpty() ? 
                          null : 
                          subscribersList.values().iterator().next();
        this.converters = converters;
    }
 ...
 }
```

**YAML-config:**

```
...
subscribersList:
  sub1:
    kafkaBroker: xxx:9092
    topicName: saveTopic
    healthCheckTimeout: 10
    producerTimeout: 10
...
```

**Class 2:**

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class KafkaConfig {

    private final Subscriber subscriberProps;
    private final Map<String, Object> producerProps;

    public KafkaConfig(KafkaProperties kafkaProps,
                       SplitterProps appProps) {
        this.subscriberProps = appProps.subscriber;      ֎ 2 ֎
        this.producerProps = getProducerProperties(kafkaProps, subscriberProps);
    }
...
}
```

If there IS **@Validated** annotation in row ֎ 1 ֎

then **appProps.subscriber == null** in row ֎ 2 ֎. (NPE arised)

If there is NO **@Validated** annotation in row ֎ 1 ֎

then **appProps.subscriber != null** in row ֎ 2 ֎. (works as expected)

Why could it be and how to avoid it?

Answer (score 2):

Solution is the following:

- when there is **no** @Validate annotation on @ConfigurationProperties class
  then calling appProps.subscriber refers to **instance of SplitterProps class**.
- when there **is** @Validate annotation on @ConfigurationProperties class
  then SplitterProps wraps into Spring proxy so calling appProps.subscriber **refers to proxy member**.

To handle this behavior I should perform field access **via getter**.

So I've added @Getter to SplitterProps class and now appProps.getSubscriber() != null.